# How can I get the assests version value in Symfony2 or Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to display in the footer of my app the assets version set in app/config.yml file:

```
framework:
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_version: v2.6.2
```

How can I get in Twig or in a controller the **assets_version** value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AssetsExtension's getAssetsVersion method.

So, in a controller:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getVersion();
```

Or in a Twig file:

```
{{ assets_version() }}
```

Check https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Extension/AssetsExtension.php

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recent Symfony version and your configuration on **config.yml** looks like this

```
framework:
    assets:
        version: "your_assets_version"
```

You can use:

```
{{ asset_version('') }}
```

For more detail check https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset-version